# 2013 - Get URL and picture from mysite in Search result webpart display template

Tags: 2013, display-template

I have a search result webpart and want to display users there. The users are in a list (the field is a people picker). I registered the field as a managed property. I can get the name of the Person in the people picker without problems in my display template. But I am not able to gather the url of the mysite and the picture url from the mysite from the person since the managed property can't be of the type "people".

How do I get the url of the mysite and the image in my display template?

Comment: What do you want to do? An employee directory?

Comment: yes. Show the employees of a specific team. This already works, I am just missing the link to the mysite and the image.

Comment: I am doing the same, but without a list. I use only the properties from the Active Directory (MySites). Would that also be possible for you?

Comment: Here you can see how I did it (of course modified it a little for my purpose): http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/ also here something: http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/eskaggs/archive/2014/11/10/sharepoint-2013-displaying-people-search-results-in-multiple-columns/

Comment: Sadly not, our active directory isn't updated very well.

Comment: I highly recommend to use the properties in AD which you already have. The user can change properties in his/her MySite. The MySite will contain more related information and much more... Also the work for the Administators will be less, if those properties are filled in the AD.